# Overhead image in a table,how to have fixed cell dimension

Tags: tables, graphics

I have this problem:

[image]

This is my code,i wanna have a fixed height to fit my image perfectly without scaling too much.

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|p{5cm}|}
\posizCellaRiga
\textbf{Nominativo} & \textbf{Matricola} & \textbf{Firma} \\
\posizCellaRiga
 Nicola Genesin & 1008671 & \includegraphics[scale=0.6] {../Immagini/FirmeSingolari/giulio.png} \\
\posizCellaRiga
..
..
..
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\includegraphics[heigth=10pt]{ ...}
```